# Group array of objects by "dataPrin" field

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, jscript, typescript

I have been trying for a while to group this array by the "dataPrin" field without success.

Note that I have two "dataPrin" fields displaying the same date, right!

I want to group this array so that if there are two "dataPrin" fields displaying the same date, they are grouped into just one, as in the example below.

Is it possible to use 'reduce' for this? I would like the help of the community.

Current array:

```
[{
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-31T16:10:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
            "cod_transacao": 1510,
            "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
            "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
        }]
},
{
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:30:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
            "cod_transacao": 1511,
            "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
            "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
        }]
},
{
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:15:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
            "cod_transacao": 1512,
            "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
            "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
        }]
}]
```

Desired array

```
[{
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-31T16:10:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
            "cod_transacao": 1510,
            "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
            "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
        }]
},
{
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:30:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
            "cod_transacao": 1511,
            "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
            "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
        },
        {
            "cod_transacao": 1512,
            "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
            "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
        }]
}]
```

Comment: Have you attempted to do this? Please add any code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are:

```
var data = [{
              "dataPrin": "2021-05-31T16:10:28-03:00",
              "selectAll": false,
              "lancamentos": [{
                      "cod_transacao": 1510,
                      "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
                      "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
                  }]
          },
          {
              "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:30:28-03:00",
              "selectAll": false,
              "lancamentos": [{
                      "cod_transacao": 1511,
                      "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
                      "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
                  }]
          },
          {
              "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:15:28-03:00",
              "selectAll": false,
              "lancamentos": [{
                      "cod_transacao": 1512,
                      "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
                      "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
                  }]
          }]

          const temp = data.reduce((res,item)=>{ 
            const date = item.dataPrin.split('T')[0];

            if(date in res){
              res[date].lancamentos.push(...item.lancamentos)
            }else{
              res[date] = item;
            }
            return res
          },{});
          const desired = Object.keys(temp).map(c=>temp[c])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect for `reduce()`.

```js
const data = [{
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-31T16:10:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
      "cod_transacao": 1510,
      "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
      "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
    }]
  },
  {
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:30:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
      "cod_transacao": 1511,
      "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
      "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
    }]
  },
  {
    "dataPrin": "2021-05-29T16:15:28-03:00",
    "selectAll": false,
    "lancamentos": [{
      "cod_transacao": 1512,
      "num_cpf_cnpj": "11.414.555/0001-04",
      "dt_lancamamento": "2021-05-31T16:29:28-03:00",
    }]
  }
]

let ndata = data.reduce((b, a) => {
  let iden = a.dataPrin.split("T")[0];
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(iden)) a.lancamentos.forEach(l => b[iden].lancamentos.push(l));
  else b[iden] = a;
  return b
}, {})

console.log(ndata);
```

Comment: Wordless. But still: Thank you very much.

I'll study this magic method further: Reduce